# Mapping a long data property to int in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In all of the examples that I've seen use `int32`s as the IDs. That's not always practical in production environments. Several of our databases have identity IDs that are in the realm of `int64`s, so our practice is to always use `long` for our ID properties. However, SQL Server has higher max values for the `int` column type.

I'm doing our first proof of concept with Entity Framework version 6. With the `long ID`, it's unable to map the object to the database.

I'm using Fluent API for all of my mapping. Right now, it looks like this for the ID:

```
Property(s => s.ID).HasColumnName("spcID");
```

If I add a `.HasColumnType("int")` to the end of the above, it gives me the following error:

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors:  (7,12) : error 2019: Member
>   Mapping specified is not valid. The type
>   'Edm.Int64[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=]' of member 'ID' in type
>   'EFConnection.Space' is not compatible with
>   'SqlServer.int[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,StoreGeneratedPattern=Identity]'
>   of member 'spcID' in type 'CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.Space'.

How do you map the datatype for these to a long variable in .NET?

**Edit**

Right now, I have a simple Integration Test set up to make sure that I can connect:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1() {
    using (var context = new Context()) {
        Assert.IsTrue(context.Spaces.Any());
        Assert.IsTrue(context.Spaces.First().IsActive);
    }
}
```

Without the `.HasColumnType("int")`, the first Assert passes, but I get an `InvalidOperationException` on the second:

> The 'ID' property on 'Space' could not be set to a 'System.Int32' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Int64'.

Comment: Does it work without `.HasColumnType(...)`? I recall using EF4 and never used the constraint, seemed to work fine mapping SQL `int` to C#'s `long` values.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. If you're using an `int` in SQL, use an `int` in C#. If you're using a `bigint` in SQL, use a `long` in C#. They both hold the same value range; see Trevor's answer.

Comment: Looking at Trevor's answer, it looks like our convention of `int` in the database and `long` in C# was incorrect. At best, it's future proofing the data layer.

Comment: If you're attempting to future-proof, why not have both be `long`/`bigint`? It's dumb to have one be an `int` and one be a `long`. What happens when you get above the value that an `int` can hold? Your code runs, but crashes when you attempt to persist it in the database - and that's a problem.

Comment: Oh I totally agree. As I said under Trevor's answer, I was told that SQL's `int` has a much larger range. I'm just giving the reasons I was given. The fact that those reasons are incorrect changes my views on them, and I'm going to stop defending them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C# and SQL data types are compatible:

If your table has a column of `bigint` use `public long Id { get; set; }` if your column is `int` use `public int Id { get; set; }`

**SQL**

bigint `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808` to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`
int `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`

**C#**

long `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808` to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`
int `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`

References:

- [int, bigint, smallint, and tinyint (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx)
- [int (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w.aspx)
- [long (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx)

Comment: Interesting! I could have sworn they had different min/max values. Thanks for that.

Comment: @SiLo why would they? It's either a 32bit or 64bit value.

Comment: OK. This has me curious about the effectiveness of my company's standards. Perhaps the data-layer is getting future-proofed, and should they hit the limit in the database they alter the column. I'm with @SiLo and thought that they had different min/max values.

Comment: @krillgar - `int` in the database and `long` in the class isn't future proofing the code - it's a time bomb!

Comment: Agreed. I believe the thought was that it's easy to run a column update in the database, and having to roll out a new DLL is a lot of work. It definitely is not good practice though.

Comment: bigint use public long Id { get; set; }    nice that worked

Comment: There's one problem (at least with EF core - if I use models that have `long Id` but the database has int identifiers, EF throws `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Int64'`. That's weird, why not just cast it automagically to a superior type? I guess, I'll have to add manual Id mappings everywhere for the database in question.